# I would like to load generated vue chunk files in a sub-folder

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, webpack

I have developed a web app in vuejs. The app development is finished and I am willing to publish it on a VPS server. I am a little bit confused on how to build the app for production. 
However, the `dist` folder is been served using Express JS framework.

```
var path = require('path');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get(/.*/, (req, res)=>{
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});


app.listen(port);
console.log('server started '+ port);
```

This implementation serves the app in `http://127.0.0.1:5000` and loads all the CSS and JS files within that directory. 
What I really want to achieve is to serve the app in `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` and load the generated chunk files in a sub-directory such as `assets`.
so in order for the app to access a single CSS file, it has to look for `http://127.0.0.1:5000/assets/css/apxxxx.css`